# Is there any way to find string is a number (either int, long, float or double) in C#?

Tags: c#

Is there any class in `C#` similar to `Numberformat` class in `Java` which, verify the string is a number.

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance();
Number number = numberFormat.parse(string);
```

---

while trying for float with following parameter
 float.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out fValue),

the value=6666.77777 is rounded of to 6666.778.

can anyone help, i don't want my value to be rounded.

Comment: `int.TryParse(...)`, `float.TryParse(...)`, `long.TryParse(...)`, `double.TryParse(...)`...

Answer (score 6):

use `int.TryParse` it will return true if the number is int.

- [int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) for integers.
- [float.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.tryparse.aspx) for floats.
- [double.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse.aspx) for doubles
- [Int64.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xssxkb0k.aspx) for long.

e.g.

```
string str = "123";
int temp;
if (int.TryParse(str, out temp))
{
    //its an int
}
else
{
    // not an int
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int a
bool isNumber = int.TryParse("500", out a);
```

replace `int` with whatever number you want to check for